# how to visualize dependence of model performance & alpha with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, regression

I fit a Ridge Regression with GridSearchCV but am having trouble using `matplotlib` to show the model performance versus regularizer(alpha)

Could anyone please help?

My code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
cal=fetch_california_housing()
X = cal.data
y = cal.target 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

param_grid = {'alpha': np.logspace(-3, 3, 13)}
print(param_grid)
grid = GridSearchCV(Ridge(normalize=True), param_grid, cv=10)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Best cross-validation score: {:.2f}".format(grid.best_score_))
print("Best parameters: ", grid.best_params_)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
alphas = np.logspace(-3, 3, 13)
plt.semilogx(alphas, grid.fit(X_train, y_train), label='Train')
plt.semilogx(alphas, grid.fit(X_test, y_test), label='Test')

plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.ylim([0, 1.0])
plt.xlabel('alpha')
plt.ylabel('performance')

# the error code I got was "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension"
```

Basically, I want to see the something like the following:

[image: change of alpha]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When plotting model selection performance resulting from using GridSearch, it's typical to plot the mean and standard deviation of test and training sets of the cross_validation folds.

Also care should be taken to identify which scoring criteria is to be used in the grid search to select the best model. this is typically R-squared for regression.

The grid search returns a dictionary (accessible through `.cv_results_`) containing the scores for each fold train/test scores as well as the time it took to train/test each fold. Also a summary of that data is included using the mean and the standard deviation.
PS. in newer version of scikit-learn you'll need to include `return_train_score=True`
PS.S. when using grid search, splitting the data to train/test is not necessary for model selection, because the grid search splits the data automatically (cv=10 means that the data is split to 10 folds)

given the above I modified the code to

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
cal = fetch_california_housing()
X = cal.data
y = cal.target


param_grid = {'alpha': np.logspace(-3, 3, 13)}
print(param_grid)
grid = GridSearchCV(Ridge(normalize=True), param_grid,
                    cv=10, return_train_score=True, scoring='r2')
grid.fit(X, y)
print("Best cross-validation score: {:.2f}".format(grid.best_score_))
print("Best parameters: ", grid.best_params_)


alphas = np.logspace(-3, 3, 13)

train_scores_mean = grid.cv_results_["mean_train_score"]
train_scores_std = grid.cv_results_["std_train_score"]
test_scores_mean = grid.cv_results_["mean_test_score"]
test_scores_std = grid.cv_results_["std_test_score"]

plt.figure()
plt.title('Model')
plt.xlabel('$\\alpha$ (alpha)')
plt.ylabel('Score')
# plot train scores
plt.semilogx(alphas, train_scores_mean, label='Mean Train score',
             color='navy')
# create a shaded area between [mean - std, mean + std]
plt.gca().fill_between(alphas,
                       train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                       train_scores_mean + train_scores_std,
                       alpha=0.2,
                       color='navy')
plt.semilogx(alphas, test_scores_mean,
             label='Mean Test score', color='darkorange')

# create a shaded area between [mean - std, mean + std]
plt.gca().fill_between(alphas,
                       test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                       test_scores_mean + test_scores_std,
                       alpha=0.2,
                       color='darkorange')

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

The resulting figure is shown below
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is helpful. But I am curious that you said "when using grid search, splitting the data to train/test is not necessary for model selection" I didn't know this so I always split train/test data, do you mind passing some reference?

Comment: You're welcome. here is a hastily obtained ref [scikit-learn cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation) ***A test set should still be held out for final evaluation, but the validation set is no longer needed when doing CV. In the basic approach, called k-fold CV, the training set is split into k smaller sets (other approaches are described below, but generally follow the same principles). The following procedure is followed for each of the k “folds”:***

Comment: The reason I raised the point above, is that you're holding 33% of the data for validation. note the terminology can be confusing. the test score we're plotting are related to the kfolds and X_test, y_test are not seen when the model is selected by gridsearch. I recommend using different terminology to elevate confusion i.e. `X_model_sel, X_val, y_model_sel, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)`

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I just tried split/no split, and the CV scores varied quite a bit(.61 v.s. .51). I think the reason (in my case) is, when splitting, the gridsearch is doing it only on the 70% of the whole dataset(which means gridsearch does the cv on it by further splitting it into another 70/30%?). While no splitting, gridsearch takes the whole dataset and runs cv on the 70% of the data. Do you agree?

Comment: I agree with minor correction; when using cross validation with cv=10 the data is split into 10 parts i.e. 10% /90% then each part is used for training while the rest used for validation. I recommend setting the grid search parameter `grid = GridSearchCV(Ridge(normalize=True), param_grid,
                    cv=10, return_train_score=True, verbose=5)` you'll get a better sense of how the grid search works

Comment: PS. the drop in the performance is due to the fact that the function `train_test_split` shuffles the data by default. shuffling the data usually enhances performance (only for non-temporal data).  so compromise would be to split the data 5%/95% this you'll take advantage of the shuffling and validate the model on unseen data. i.e. `X_model_sel, X_val, y_model_sel, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.05,random_state=0)`

Comment: Thanks! A quick follow-up. When you said 'shuffles', does that mean that the it randomly pick rows out of the whole data set till it fulfill the 95% threshold, instead of drawing rows in any particular order? Also, at the risk of digressing, I want to ask you about `Ridge(normalize=True)`, which I assume normalize it `center` plus 'scale'. Due to the uncertainty in features, I was thinking perhaps I should only `scale` considering the directionality problem after `center`. I fit another `Lasso` with normalization, and the score is very poor, that makes me consider this.

Comment: You're welcome. re: shuffles:Yes,spoton. re: normalised: X is (preprocessed) normalised by subtracting the mean and dividing by the l2-norm. depending on the nature of the data, you may want to consider other feature scaling techniques. I highly recommend checking [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing).

Answer (score 2):

you should plot scores, not the result of `grid.fit()`.

First of all use `return_train_score=True`:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(Ridge(normalize=True), param_grid, cv=10, return_train_score=True)
```

then after fitting the model plot it as follows:

```
plt.semilogx(alphas, grid.cv_results_['mean_train_score'], label='Train')
plt.semilogx(alphas, grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score'], label='Test')
plt.legend()
```

Result:

[image]